# Items in a flexbox adjusting their widths automatically so that they occupy the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I put three items in a flexbox that has different amount of content, by default the `align-items` is set to `stretch` and thus the height of all the columns of a flexbox is same. However, I want it to be such that the text in each of the columns occupies the full height available to it, while automatically adjusting the width. How do I achieve this?

I'm attaching a sample code for it.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    border: 2px red;
    border-style: solid;
}
.col1{
    background-color: brown;
    color:white;
}
.col{
    border: 2px green;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col2">
        <h1>Hello friends</h1>
        <p>An article (with the linguistic glossing abbreviation art) is a word that is used with a noun (as a standalone word or a prefix or suffix) to specify grammatical definiteness of the noun, and in some languages extending to volume or numerical scope. The articles in English grammar are the and a/an, and in certain contexts some. "An" and "a" are modern forms of the Old English "an", which in Anglian dialects was the number "one" (compare "on" in Saxon dialects) and survived into Modern Scots as the number "owan". Both "on" (respelled "one" by the Norman language) and "an" survived into Modern English, with "one" used as the number and "an" ("a", before nouns that begin with a consonant sound) as an indefinite article.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
        <h1>Bye friends</h1>
        <p>An article (with the linguistic glossing abbreviation art) is a word that is used with a noun (as a standalone word or a prefix or suffix) to specify grammatical definiteness of the noun, and in some languages extending to volume or numerical scope. The articles in English grammar are the and a/an, and in certain contexts some. "An" and "a" are modern forms of the Old English "an", which in Anglian dialects was the number "one" (compare "on" in Saxon dialects) and survived into Modern Scots as the number "owan". Both "on" (respelled "one" by the Norman language) and "an" survived into Modern English, with "one" used as the number and "an" ("a", before nouns that begin with a consonant sound) as an indefinite article.</p>
        <p>An article (with the linguistic glossing abbreviation art) is a word that is used with a noun (as a standalone word or a prefix or suffix) to specify grammatical definiteness of the noun, and in some languages extending to volume or numerical scope. The articles in English grammar are the and a/an, and in certain contexts some. "An" and "a" are modern forms of the Old English "an", which in Anglian dialects was the number "one" (compare "on" in Saxon dialects) and survived into Modern Scots as the number "owan". Both "on" (respelled "one" by the Norman language) and "an" survived into Modern English, with "one" used as the number and "an" ("a", before nouns that begin with a consonant sound) as an indefinite article.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col1">
        <p>An article (with the linguistic glossing abbreviation art) is a word that is used with a noun (as a standalone word or a prefix or suffix) to specify grammatical definiteness of the noun, and in some languages extending to volume or numerical scope.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I suppose, it should be solved by using flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis property, but I can't find how to use that

P.S. - the text is copied from Wikipedia

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the *text* to occupy the full height". You want more text to magically appear from somewhere?

Comment: @TylerH I want the width of that column to be decreased so that the all the three columns occupy the same height. Makes sense?

Comment: @user185887 I understand your question but answer is: no.

Comment: this is impossible, even with JS you wil have a hard time doing it

Comment: Are you looking for CSS `columns`?

Comment: There is no way by using `flex` to achieve elastic text columns that automaticly adjust their width in dependetion on their height.

Comment: @user185887 So you want the column with the most text to expand in width until it's the same height (with text wrapping enabled) as the other columns (and vice versa with the column with the smallest amount of text)?

Comment: @TylerH Yes thats what I intended to do. chriskirknielsen's comment has got the point